# How do i change path to folder location when writing a .txt document?

Tags: c#, path, substring, filestream, lastindexof

I'm using `filestream` to write a text document. Everything seems to work fine except that the document is directed to the wrong folder.

This is where the code thinks it should create the document:

```
C:\Users\user2\Desktop\work\SuperBy\nop\NopCommerceStore\Administration\FedEx
```

The `FedEx` folder dosn't exist in the Administration folder.  But if I create a `FedEx` folder and place it in the `Administration` folder, the `.txt` documents appear accordingly.

This is the actual path do the folder in which the documents should be written:

```
C:\Users\user2\Desktop\work\SuperBy\nop\NopCommerceStore\FedEx
```

I simply don't understand how the code works and how to change it, really need some help with this.

```
try
{
    Order o = IoC.Resolve<IOrderService>().GetOrderById(orderID);
    Customer ThisCustomer = o.Customer;

    // Specify file, instructions, and privelegdes
    string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath;
    int index = path.LastIndexOf("\\");
    string realPath = path.Substring(0, index + 1);
    FileStream file = new FileStream(realPath + "/FedEx/" + orderID.ToString() + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
}
```

Comment: realPath + "/../FedEx/" might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
    Order o = IoC.Resolve<IOrderService>().GetOrderById(orderID);
    Customer ThisCustomer = o.Customer;

    // Specify file, instructions, and privelegdes
    string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath;
    int index = path.LastIndexOf("\\");
    string realPath = path.Substring(0, index + 1);
    FileStream file = new FileStream(realPath + "/../FedEx/" +
        orderID.ToString() + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basing it off your statements, I believe you want to create the path like this:

```
try
{
    Order o = IoC.Resolve<IOrderService>().GetOrderById(orderID);
    Customer ThisCustomer = o.Customer;

    // Specify file, instructions, and privelegdes
    string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath;

    // this should give me the index at which the "\administration" part of the
    // path starts so we can cut it off
    int index = path.IndexOf("\\administration",
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    // when building the path we substring from 0 to the index of the
    // "\administration" part of the string, add "FedEx", the order id,
    // and then finally ".txt"
    string realPath = Path.Combine(path.Substring(0, index), "FedEx",
        orderID.ToString(), ".txt");

    // now open the file
    FileStream file = new FileStream(realPath,
        FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
        FileAccess.Write);
}
```

Also, `Path.Combine` is really key here. When building paths it can very quickly become problematic getting `\` in the right places--it handles that seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with combine but i created a "addkey" in "appsettings" in the web.config and used the local link as value, you know c:/user/..etc However using a lokal link dosn't seem to be the best idea and i would rather try a more abstract solution. Im currently running NopCommerce on localhost but will upload it on server later on. Thanks for the tip =)

Comment: It didn't work. I see you wroye \\administration but the file is suposed to be saved in NopCommerceStore. Meaby it works changing folder location?

Comment: @KristofferAndersson, the idea of `\\Administration` was to find the index at which it started so I could cut it off. It's possible the string comparison needs to be non-ordinal because I noticed you wrote `\\administration` with a lowercase `a`.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath` is returning,

> C:\Users\user2\Desktop\work\SuperBy\nop\NopCommerceStore\Administration,

Thus, you need drop `\Administration` before appending `FedEx` to `realPath`.

Comment: I see but how do i alter the physical path as it is currently directed to the admin folder? I mean how do i drop it?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the item any place you want. If you want to have control over this you could use:

```
try
{
    Order o = IoC.Resolve<IOrderService>().GetOrderById(orderID);
    Customer ThisCustomer = o.Customer;
    FileStream file = new FileStream("C:/Users/user2/Desktop/work/SuperBy/nop/NopCommerceStore/FedEx/" + orderID.ToString() + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
}
```

Now its more obvious how you can change your code to use a different path. Its very important to keep your code readable to anyone who should ever read it. In this case that is yourself.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. This is more readable. Thanks for the imput!